# Какой тип должен быть у представления в @model ...?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

В контроллере следующий код:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FullHome model = new FullHome();
            var lastId = _context.UserPortfolio.Max(p=>p.IdPortfolio);



            var portfolioUser = from portfolio in _context.UserPortfolio where portfolio.IdPortfolio > lastId - 4
                         join user in _context.UserProfile on portfolio.IdUser equals user.IdUser
                         join image in _context.ImgPortfolio on portfolio.IdPortfolio equals image.IdPortfolio
                         select new
                         {
                             Portfolio = portfolio,
                             TypePortfolio = portfolio.TypePortfolio,
                             DescriptionPortfolio = portfolio.DescriptionPortfolio.Substring(0, 150) + "...",
                             DatePortfolio = portfolio.DatePortfolio,
                             IdUser = user.IdUser,
                             NameUser = user.NameUser,
                             ImagePortfolio = image.DataImg
                         };

            return View(portfolioUser);
        }
```

Хочу перечислить три последние добавленные записи из таблицы

Comment: Так вы вместо создания анонимного типа, создайте класс модели и пользуйтесь им.

Comment: А как присвоить созданной модели результат такого выражения?

Comment: Очень просто. Вместо `select new ...` в вашем выражении сделайте `select new MyClassModel ....`. Ну и соответственно определите свой класс `public class MyClassModel` с нужными вам полями.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье